# From raw data to UIImagePNGRepresentation in fewer steps

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift3, nsdata, uiimagepngrepresentation

Using this code, I *extract* an image from a Share Extension and I write it to a directory I created in an App Group.

```
let content = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem

   let contentType = kUTTypeImage as String

      for attachment in content.attachments as! [NSItemProvider] {

         if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {

            attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil) { data, error in

            // from here
            if error == nil {

               let url = data as! NSURL
               let originalFileName = url.lastPathComponent

               if let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {

                  let img = UIImage(data:imageData as Data)

                  if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img!) {
                     // write, etc.
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Anything is working fine.

What I'd like to know is if it is possible to reduce some code: in particular, after `if error == nil`, I:

- cast data to `NSURL`;
- use `NSURL` to get a `NSData`;
- use `NSData` to get a `UIImage`;
- use `UIImage` to get a `UIImagePNGRepresentation`;

Aside from avoiding the creation of the imageData variable, isn't there a way to (safely) achieve the same goal with fewer steps?

Comment: You don't need these two steps *use NSData to get a UIImage;
use UIImage to get a UIImagePNGRepresentation;*

Comment: @MidhunMP: are you suggesting I can directly write imageData in the final step?

Comment: You can use the NSData got from the server and write that directly

Comment: @MidhunMP Problem is I want a PNG, even if it is a JPG   :-)

Comment: @IanBell You can still write that data as png, simply give file name as `.png`  and write data in Document directory, it will automatically create image with png extension from that data.

Comment: @NiravD: I'm not writing to Documents but to a custom directory in an App Group (but I suppose your suggestion is true in any case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to use native `Data` and `URL` instead of `NSData` & `NSURL` also if you want to write file in `DocumentDirectory` then you can directly use that imageData no need to make `UIImage` object from it and then convert it to data using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

```
if let url = data as? URL, error == nil {

    let originalFileName = url.lastPathComponent
    if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: data) {
        // write, etc.
        var destinationURL  = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        destinationURL.appendPathComponent("fileName.png")
        try? imageData.write(to: destinationURL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Documents directory is not involved

Comment: Moreover, data is of type NSSecureCoding? and I need it as NSURL (or URL)

Comment: @IanBell Have you try `data as! URL`?

Comment: data as URL works, but in your code you don't use it   :-)

Comment: @IanBell If you doesn't want to write imageData on directory do what you want.